# Scripted cmdlets and compiled cmdlets in a single module?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have written *compiled modules* (i.e. PS modules written in C#), where one specifies the DLL as the `RootModule` in the manifest, and I have written *scripted modules* (PS modules written in PowerShell), where one specifies the .psm1 file as the `RootModule`, but is it possible to include cmdlets of *both* type in a *single* module?

As a temporary measure (while I am developing some new code) I specified my DLL as the `RootModule` and listed my scripted cmdlets in `ScriptsToProcess`. That makes all the cmdlets accessible, but not properly, in that `Get-Command -module MyModule` only lists those cmdlets coming from the `RootModule` as one might expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, we do this on the PowerShell Community Extensions like so:

```
RootModule         = 'Pscx.psm1'
NestedModules      = 'Pscx.dll'
```

Comment: That makes sense... Just one question, Keith: is there a reason to prefer the .psm1 as the root and the .dll as the nested?

Comment: I don't think it matters much unless you want to do some processing at import time.  We do some processing in pscx.psm1 at import. We check a config file to determine which nested modules the user wants loaded and then do an import-module on those psm1 files.

Comment: Actually I found it _does_ matters for my use case: needing to load some compiled cmdlets (from a dll) and some scripted cmdlets (from a psm1). If I set `RootModule` to the dll and `NestedModules` to the psm1, then `gcm -module MyModule` lists _all_ cmdlets, some designated Function and some designated Cmdlet for CommandType, as expected. If I simply swap the two property assignments and reload the module, then _only_ the scripted cmdlets load (Function CommandType). You do not have that scenario in the PSCX manifest, so you would not see the issue. Nevertheless, thanks for getting me going!

Comment: I think it could be that you have to explicitly export the compiled cmdlets via the manifest's CmdletsToExport field when the DLL is specified in NestedModules.

Comment: Good thought, Keith... just tried it but, no, it did not help.